# Python My programming Lab

Tags: python-2.7

I have a problem doing one of the questions from my programming lab.
The question was like "Given the variables  x, y, and z, each associated with an int, write a fragment of code that assigns the smallest of these to min."
And my work area looks like

```
if x < y and x < z:
  x = min
    if y < x and y < z:
        y = min
        if z < x and z < y:
            z = min
```

When I turned in, the feedback said:
Remarks:
     ⇒     Unexpected identifiers: and

More Hints:
     ⇒     Solutions with your approach don't usually use: <

although I tried may ways to figure it out but none of them worked.
Plz help.
Thx.

For the first reply, the system said:
Remarks:
     ⇒     Unexpected identifiers: and

More Hints:
     ⇒     Solutions with your approach don't usually use: <

Problems Detected:
     ⇒     Exception occurred(, TypeError('unorderable types: int() < builtin_function_or_method()',), )
     ⇒     Exception occurred(, TypeError('unorderable types: int() < builtin_function_or_method()',), )
     ⇒     Exception occurred(, TypeError('unorderable types: int() < builtin_function_or_method()',), )
     ⇒     Exception occurred(, TypeError('unorderable types: int() < builtin_function_or_method()',), )
     ⇒     min does not contain the correct value
     ⇒     y was modified
     ⇒     z was modified

For the second reply, the system said:

Remarks:
     ⇒     Unexpected identifiers: and, def, minist
     ⇒     You have to use the min variable .
     ⇒     You should use an assignment operator (=) in this exercise.

More Hints:
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: =
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: min
     ⇒     I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: , (comma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues with the code as you've shown it in the question.

The first is that your indentation is a bit messed up. You probably want all your `if` statements to be at the same level, with the corresponding assignment statements indented under each one:

```
if something:
    foo = bar
if something_else:
    foo = baz
# etc
```

You could also use `elif` statements instead of the second and third `if`, since you never expect to have more than one of the conditions true at the same time.

The second issue is that you're doing your assignment statements backwards. If you want to assign the value in a variable `x` to a new variable named `min`, you should put `min` on the left side and `x` on the right:

```
min = x
```

This is part of the reason you're getting lots of confusing errors. Before your code runs, `min` is the name of a builtin function (which I suspect you'll learn about later in your class). When you did `x = min` you were replacing the old `x` value with a reference to the function.

The last thing is a logic issue. Your comparisons are all using the `<` operator to test if one value is smaller than the others. The issue is what happens if two of the values are equal. If `x` and `y` have the same value, both `x < y` and `y < x` will be `False`. That's not very good for your code, and so you probably want to use the `<=` operator instead. It tests if the left side is less than or equal to the right side. With this version, if you're using `elif`s, you can actually do away with the last condition and just use `else`, since if neither `x` or `y` is less than or equal to the other values, `z` must be the smallest value by process of elimination.

Anyway, here's the code with all three issues fixed:

```
if x <= y and x <= z:
    min = x
elif y <= x and y <= z:
    min = y
else: # no "z <= x and z <= y" check needed here, will always be true if reached
    min = z
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tab problem.

You can try this:

```
if x < y and x < z:
    x = min
if y < x and y < z:
    y = min
if z < x and z < y:
    z = min
```

Comment: Here's what the system said:

Comment: CODELAB ANALYSIS: LOGICAL ERROR(S)

Remarks:
     ⇒     Unexpected identifiers: and

Answer (score 0):

I make a sample:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def minist(x,y,z):
if x < y and x < z:
    return x
if y < x and y < z:
    return y
if z < x and z < y:
    return z



x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

test = -1

test = minist(x,y,z)

print(test)
```

This sample will print 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The system said:
Remarks:
     ⇒     Unexpected identifiers: and, def, minist
     ⇒     You have to use the min variable .
     ⇒     You should use an assignment operator (=) in this exercise.

More Hints:
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: =
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: min
     ⇒     I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: , (comma)